# inequality with two parameters

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Determine $a,b \in \mathbb R$ so that the following real function is convex:
> $$f(x) = \cos(ax) + e^{bx^2}.$$

I know that a function is convex if the 2nd derivative is greater/equal zero. But I am struggling to solve the inequality:

$$-a^2 \cos (ax) + 4b^2 x^2 e^{bx^2} +2be^{bx^2} \ge 0.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I was looking for those sites. thank you!

Comment: Start by setting $x=0$ in $-a^2 \cos (ax) + 4b^2 x^2 e^{bx^2} +2be^{bx^2} \ge 0$, that gives you a necessary condition for convexity. Can you show that this condition is also sufficient?

Comment: Brilliant! If we set x= 0 , we just have to solve the inequality 2b-a^2 ≥0, so √2b≤a.
This condition is sufficient, since for the exp() part x is always positive because it is squared, so 0 is the lowest possible value. For the other part, we know cos(ax) has values between -1 and 1, so therefore cos(0)=1 is the lowest possible for the whole part. Thank you very much!